# Github Actions: On pull request in specified direction?

Tags: github, github-actions

I'm trying to figure out how to only trigger a workflow/action when a pull-request is issues from `dev` to `main`, but not the other way around. I found that by using the following syntax:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
```

.. causes the workflow/action to trigger even if we do `main -> dev`, not only `dev -> main`. Is there a way to enforce that the action only happens on the `dev -> main` direction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve what your want, you could just include:

```
on:
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main"
```

Note that in your question:

- `pull_request:` (in short) is the defective version of

  ```
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "**"  # all branches are targeted
  ```
- but the other part of your YAML code should be kept:

  ```
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
  ```

  meaning, (independently of `pull_request` *reviews*),
  each direct push to `main` (and any PR *merge* in `main`) triggers the workflow.

See also the [official documentation of workflows' syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#onpull_requestpull_request_targetbranchesbranches-ignore):

> When using the `pull_request` and `pull_request_target` events, you can configure a workflow to run only for pull requests that **target** specific branches.

#### Wrap-up

Hence the following snippet:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "main"
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - "main"
```

Answer (score 1):

it is possible. See docs here: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/events-that-trigger-workflows#running-your-pull_request-workflow-based-on-the-head-or-base-branch-of-a-pull-request

In your example that would be:

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    branches:
      - 'main'
```

This will run on all pushes to `main` AND when there is a pull-request for `main`.